# ctypes can't find find dll function

Tags: python, c++, dll, ctypes

I'm a complete beginner at C++ and have been trying to access a C++ function from Python using a DLL through ctypes.
I always get the error `AttributeError: function 'my_function' not found` when running my code.

Header.h

```
#pragma once

int my_function(void);
```

Source.cpp

```
#include "Header.h"

int my_function(void)
{
    return(17); //test
}
```

ctypesTest.py

```
import ctypes

if __name__ == "__main__":

    mydll = ctypes.CDLL("MyDLL.dll")

    print(mydll.my_function())
```

Every time I run the Python script I get the attribute error.

I only need values out of my intended function.

Comment: Maybe this is because you are missing [`extern "C"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c-in-c) around the function declaration?

Comment: You also may need to explicitly export the function with `__declspec(dllexport)`. I don't think Windows exports functions from DLLs by default.

Comment: @MikelRychliski Thank you very much. When I implemented both of your suggestions the program worked. I'd been puzzling over this for hours.

Comment: This page has some good info for Windows vs Linux too: http://wolfprojects.altervista.org/articles/dll-in-c-for-python/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Mikel Rychliski answered my question.

Header.h

```
#pragma once

#define DllExport __declspec( dllexport )

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) int my_function(void);
}
```